# Kentico form control to select multiple files from media library

Tags: kentico

Kentico 13. We have a page type 'ImageGallery' which should enable an editor to select multiple images from a media library. Is there a form control for multiple media selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a form control to do this.

However...

A better, more robust approach is to have an image gallery page type that defines the gallery, then have a content only (no navigation) image page type that you add directly as children of the image gallery page.  Each image allows you to assign a name, select a media library image, set a caption or description, assign any seo values, and accessibility attributes.

Using this method allows you a more robust approach because you can use published to and from dates, workflow, and add any custom fields you want, not to forget have multiple images.

**** UPDATED ANSWER ****
Due to your comment regarding how you plan to use the system, what you can do then is select a folder in the media library and based on the folder path, you can select all the files under that path.  I don't believe there is anything out of the box that allows a media library folder selection but you could look and see if you can make one of the other controls work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But doing so would require high editorial efforts, right? So we would need some sort of automation process.

Comment: Define "high editorial efforts".  You have 100 times more functionality using a media library image WITH a specific content type for those images.  Been using Kentico Xperience since 2008 and it's a highly recommended practice vs. using a widget approach because of the lack of flexibility of the widget and need to build a lot of custom widget controls to "make it work" whereas what I described allows you to use OOTB functionality.

Comment: Thanks and don't get wrong: I'm new with Kentico and really appreciate your help and advice.

Comment: Our scenario is as follows: We have an external image provider that will provide us with live photos from events. Our idea was to organize the photos in event specific medialibrary folders. In an ideal world, content editors would preview the images in the media library, select and import some of them (including EXIF data). Best photos are editorially curated in photo galleries. On top of that we need to crop every image into defined ratios (optionally allowing an editor to set the focus point) :-(

Comment: Updated answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I am PM for a Kentico 12 MVC Website and our developer did it somehow very comfortable.

She have developed a widget with an Image selector. The editors needs to select only one picture from that folders and the system then reads out all other pictures and display all Images in that folders in the Gallery.